# can you confirm my solution for the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If S is the subspace spanned by $$ 
 \pmatrix{1 \\ 2\\1}\ \pmatrix{-1 \\ 1\\-1}\ $$ then find a basis for the orthogonal complement of S ?

the solution is:

since the null space of any matrix is the orthogonal compliment of the row apace then we solve for the null space $Ax=0$

$$ 
\pmatrix{1&2&1 \\ -1&1&-1}X=0\  $$

and tha basis will be $$ 
\pmatrix{-1 \\ 0\\1}\ $$

is this the right answer ? and thank you

Comment: You can check to see that you have the right answer by confirming that the vector in your answer is in fact orthogonal to both of the basis vectors in your problem.  It is, and therefore your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz  thank you very much for confirming and for that info

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix form as $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
By construction, the row space of $A$ is equal to $S$. Therefore, since the nullspace of any matrix is the orthogonal complement of the row space, it must be the case that $S^{⊥}=$ nul$(A)$.

The reduced row echelon form of the above matrix is $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ The matrix $A$ is now in reduced echelon form, so we can see that the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ is equivalent to $$x_1=-x_3$$
$$x_2=0$$
So, the following is a basis for nul$(A) =S^⊥$
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So, your answer is correct.

Comment: thank you very much for confirming and for explaining that

Answer (score 0):

You could also take the cross product of the two vectors to get an orthogonal vector:  $\begin{vmatrix} i&j&k\\1&2&1\\-1&1&-1\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}2&1\\1&-1\end{vmatrix}i-\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{vmatrix}j+\begin{vmatrix}1&2\\-1&1\end{vmatrix}k=-3i+3k$.  Thus we get $\begin{pmatrix}-3\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}$.

You could also pull a rabbit out of a hat and guess it, since both have $x$ and $z$ coordinates the same.

Comment: thanks for explaining other method to solve the problem